# Trying to extract dynamic URL from tag in DOM once button clicked

Tags: cypress

[image]

```
<a id="ctl00_MainContent_UndoButton" class="a-button a-button--cancel 
dd-data-link" 
href="javascript:__doPostBack('ctl00$MainContent$UndoButton','')"> 
Undo </a>
```

When i click the above button this open a new dynamic url popup which then injects the below script to open the page.

[image]

```
//<![CDATA[
ToggleTempChanged();TogglePermaChanged()
;window.open('**/products/Car/EndTempAdjustment.aspxenc
=Y/qlHvbv+Gt2rmvC4GL1GzEO87O1bd8H91aPhk96iKLRMC+yw
MY3gWzR7jpKnJVPaIz+srgg 
NtdnpsEudpo4lEa7ccLMPe2PXXQlxREtp8nsWkPq
7qKCBnVCt7n0m7f953bwfRYXrngveDlNLAqC 
wjpPP6eIp6Sz+oEtMBkjUEHJd4jztk2IEJcsHskdXH6H**');

var Page_ValidationActive = false;
if (typeof(ValidatorOnLoad) == "function") {
    ValidatorOnLoad();
}

function ValidatorOnSubmit() {
    if (Page_ValidationActive) {
        return ValidatorCommonOnSubmit();
    }
    else {
        return true;
    }
}
    
document.getElementById('ctl00_RequiredFieldValidator1').dispose = 
function() {
    Array.remove(Page_Validators, 
document.getElementById('ctl00_RequiredFieldValidator1'));
}

document.getElementById('ctl00_RegularExpressionValidator1').dispose = 
function() {
    Array.remove(Page_Validators, 
document.getElementById('ctl00_RegularExpressionValidator1'));
}
//]]>
```

I have tried all methods to try and stub, remove attributes etc for the new window to enable me to carry out tests on this page with no success and checked other answers regarding dynamic url opening new windows. Would any one know how to extract just the dynamic URL from the code that is injected above. My plan is then to cy.visit to the extracted dynamic URL.

Comment: Please use code blocks instead of images

Comment: Take a look in developer tools (ctrl-shift-I) network tab for URL and use `cy.intercept()` to catch and stub the call.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming the `CDATA` is coming to the page via and API call, you can find the URL of that call by looking in browser Developer Tools/Network tab.

The add an intercept to stub the call (so that `window.open()` portion is removed) something like

```js
cy.intercpet(url-dynamic-code, '//<![CDATA[//]]>`).as('intercept-undo')
cy.contains('Undo').click()
cy.wait('@intercept-undo')   // confirms click happened
```

Then you could `cy.visit('**/products/Car/EndTempAdjustment.aspxenc =Y/qlHv...')` to test that popup, but maybe that's not realistic since looks like popup needs to interact with main window.

Comment: Thanks, will give this a try and report findings

Comment: Above solution giving following error - Timed out retrying after 5000ms: cy.wait() timed out waiting 5000ms for the 1st request to the route: intercept-undo. No request ever occurred. The click is working as the new window is opening still.

Comment: Yes this works, the error is because you intercept with wrong URL.